# Check computer is connected to Wifi or Ethernet programmatically using Python

Tags: python, windows

I need to check whether the system is connected to WiFi or Ethernet using Python, is there any way to do so?

I have searched a lot but haven't found any way to check it via Python.

Comment: Why do you need to use python? And if there is a good reason for that, why have you spammed the [[tag:powershell]] and [[tag:batch-file]] tags for a [[tag:python]] specific question on [[tag:windows]]? This site does not provide code to order, we expect you to research your task and write your own code. Here we help you to fix a specific issue your submitted code exhibits, given sufficient information for us to reproduce it.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

os.system('netsh interface show interface')
```